# SSRS Report Does Not Refresh Via URL Access

Tags: caching, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, refresh

I want to display the output of an SSRS report in an IFrame of another application. I set the source to something like this:

```
http://SERVERNAME.domain.com/ReportServer?%2fTBI_MSCRM%2fCustomReports%2f%7bdafdbed0-1e96-e211-a5da-001d0967e0fc%7d&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false
```

The issue I am running into is that the output of the report seems to be cached for the session.

If there is a timestamp on the report that does not get updated when the page is refreshed. To see the updated data, you have to close out all browser and reopen the page. In SSRS, snapshots are not turned on, there is no cache refresh plan as the "Do not cache temporary copies of this report" option is selected.

I have take the URL out of the IFrame and run it in isolation and I get the same results, so it isn't the IFrame causing the problem. What I need is this report to refresh every time the URL is accessed.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

You can force the report server to get a new report in every request by clearing the session.

Just add the following to the URL `rs:ClearSession=true`

It would be implemented in your URL like that:

```
http://SERVERNAME.domain.com/ReportServer?%2fTBI_MSCRM%2fCustomReports%2f%7bdafdbed0-1e96-
e211-a5da-001d0967e0fc%7d&rs:Command=Render
&rs:ClearSession=true&rc:Toolbar=false
```

Clear session:

> A value of true directs the report server to remove a report from the
>   report session. All report instances associated with an authenticated
>   user are removed from the report session. (A report instance is
>   defined as the same report run multiple times with different report
>   parameter values.) The default value is false.

[for more information look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)

Comment: I wish I could double up-vote this... incredibly helpful and has made my wallboards actually work!

Comment: @Gallus  I  am glad it helped!