# SQL Reporting Service - report doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

These are the steps i perform to encounter my problem

1. User downloads the Report from the website it is associated with
2. User discovers an address is wrong so changes it
3. User downloads the report again from the website

PROBLEM: the report is automatically downloaded as a PDF using a window.open() from JavaScript, and as the parameter value is not changed, the report is downloaded as it was before and does not detect the change. So it still displays the old address.

the only Solution is to shut the browser down and then open it back up again but this isn't really a fix, so unless i set every field as a parameter then this will keep happening.

has anyone ever encountered this before or perhaps found a fix? Thankyou for any help you can give me

Comment: The issue is caused by Caching.

[This link should provide the answer you're looking for.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685857/ssrs-report-does-not-refresh-via-url-access)

Comment: perfect, post as answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by **Caching**.

Essentially all you need to do is add the following to your URL:

```
rs:ClearSession=true
```

[This link should provide the answer you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685857/ssrs-report-does-not-refresh-via-url-access)